# How would I bulk change posting date?

Tags: date-time

How would I bulk change posting date? I want to change about 20 post publish dates at a time in one click

Answer (score 1):

Post date/time can't be changed via the Quick-Edit bulk editor. You might edit the SQL directly, if you're comfortable running a query in PHPMyAdmin. Or, you could search for a Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue. I used this:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET post_date = "2008-02-13 23:50:30"
WHERE post_status = "publish"
AND post_date >=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),Interval 5 day)
```

It is updating the `wp_posts` table and changing anything published in the last 5 days to the date of 2008-02-13.

Comment: You you mind making your answer WP compatible? `$wpdb->query`, `$wpdb->posts`, etc.?